# EF Core: Multiple Where-queries simultaneously

Tags: entity-framework

I'm trying to find the best practice in EF Core regarding reading data from multiple tables with minimal performance penalty incurred by round trips to the DB. Preferably I'd like a feature like pipeline in Redis where it's possible to queue the queries which causes them to be executed in just one round trip but I suppose that's not possible in SQL. I did expect it to be possible to send all queries asynchronous though so that they are executed simultaneously so I was surprised to find that DBContext does not support multiple concurrent queries. So given that, what is the best practice in EF Core to fetch data from multiple tables without waiting for multiple back-to-back round-trips to the DB-server?

Comment: You are free to send multiple queries using multiple DbContext instances with Change Tracking disabled.  Very often, though, your app has lots of users sending queries, so it's not an improvement to send multiple queries concurrently for each user.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**Disclaimer**: I'm the owner of the project [Entity Framework Plus](https://entityframework-plus.net/)

The EF+ [Query Future](https://entityframework-plus.net/ef-core-query-future) (free and open-source) allows you to batch multiple queries and execute them in the same command.

So multiple queries get executed in just one round trip.

Example:

```
// using Z.EntityFramework.Plus; // Don't forget to include this.
var ctx = new EntitiesContext();

// CREATE a pending list of future queries
var futureCountries = ctx.Countries.Where(x => x.IsActive).Future();
var futureStates = ctx.States.Where(x => x.IsActive).Future();

// TRIGGER all pending queries in one database round trip
// SELECT * FROM Country WHERE IsActive = true;
// SELECT * FROM State WHERE IsActive = true
var countries = futureCountries.ToList();

// futureStates is already resolved and contains the result
var states = futureStates.ToList();
```

**EDIT: Answer comment**

> Does not work. Logs show that the command is executed 2 times.

Look on SQL Profiler to see if that's executed 2 times.

The log shows it 2 times because, on the first time, we need to generate the query (which use the interceptor and log the query even if not executed), and the second time the query is logged because it's now executed.

Comment: i wonder how it is different from using ExecuteStrategy and beginTransaction ? I can see that connection was opened and closed only after both queries were executed