# Searching multiple tables and fields in one efficient query

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I am trying to build a global search feature for an application that has ~40-50 tables in (and will continue to grow), with each table containing anything from 5-20 fields. I'm struggling to think of an efficient way to include a search feature.

A simplified example:

```
public class Vehicle : BaseDataEntity
{
    public string RegistrationNumber { get; set; }

    public string? VINNumber { get; set; }

    public string? Make { get; set; }

    public string? Model { get; set; }
}
```

```
public class VehicleInsurance : BaseDataEntity
{
    public string? InsuranceCompany { get; set; }

    public string? PolicyNumber { get; set; }

    public string? Type { get; set; }
}
```

```
public class Mortgage : BaseDataEntity
{
    
    public string? Type { get; set; }
    public string? Provider { get; set; }
    public string? AccountNumber { get; set; }
    public string? Amount { get; set; }
    public string? InterestRate { get; set; }
    public string? MonthlyPayment { get; set; }
    public string? StartDate { get; set; }
    public string? EndDate { get; set; }
    public string? SpecialRateStartDate { get; set; }
    public string? SpecialRateEndDate { get; set; }
}
```

I want to search the words "viva", I should match a search on a vehicle with model "viva" and vehicle insurance company "aviva", and whatever else matches.

With the number of tables/fields so large, I don't really want to have to code this out like

```
var vehicles = _dbContext.Vehicles.Where(v => v.RegistrationNumber.Contains(searchText) ||
                               v.Make.Contains(searchText) ||
                               ...And so on);
var insurances = _dbContext.VehicleInsurances.Where(v => v.InsuranceCompany.Contains(searchText) ||
                                                         v.PolicyNumber.Contains(searchText) ||
                                                         ...And so on);
...And so on with all the other tables
```

All I would be after is a reponse similar to something like this

```
public class SearchResponse
{
    public string ResultText {get;set;} // Give the full value back
    public string ResultId {get;set;} // Id of entity from BaseDataEntity
}
```

Can anyone point me to a better more efficient way (both coding and db performance) on how to achieve this?

Comment: What are you trying to do in the first place? EF is an ORM, not a query engine. It's job is to give the impression of working with objects, not tables and rows. If `Vehicle` had an `Insurance` or `Insurances` property, EF itself would load all root *and* related objects at once. The cost of roundtrips is negligible compared to the unindexable `v.RegistrationNumber.Contains(searchText)` though. That converts to `LIKE '%something%'` which can't take advantage of any indexing. The code you posted would end up scanning the entire table looking for matches.

Comment: Searching for words in the middle of text is a Full Text Search. Databases (including SQL Server) have special Full Text Search indexes and functions for this: [EF.Functions.Contains](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.sqlserverdbfunctionsextensions.contains?view=efcore-7.0) and [EF.Functions.FreeText](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.sqlserverdbfunctionsextensions.freetext?view=efcore-7.0).

Comment: FTS won't find `viva` in `aviva` though, it will find `Dogs` in `Cats and Dogs`. You can use normal indexes if you use `StartsWith`. That's why you almost always see applications offering `StartsWith` filtering but not `Contains`. `StartsWith` translates to `LIKE 'somehing%'` which in turn translates to a range search

Comment: You might want to look at solutions specifically designed for full text search, like Lucene. While some databases have some full text search features, they might not be great if you want to search for all columns. Also note that you might want to build in some intelligence in the search. If I search for a VIN number I probably want that vehicle to be listed higher than if that same VIN is mentioned in a comment field somewhere.

Answer (score -1):

You can look at [EF Plus](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62295147/ef-core-multiple-where-queries-simultaneously) for executing multiple queries without multiple db round trip

As for simplifying the query statement, you can try enumerating types in the assembly that inherits BaseDataEntity and call DbContext.Set<Type>() to get a DbSet query.

You can then use the type property enumerator to get all string-type property names and attach where clauses using EF.Property(object, propertyName).Contains(needle)

For building the response object, you can either handle each type of response separately or save all responses as IEnumerable<BaseDataEntity> and enumerable   property on each entities to get the matching property